# cm-to-inch calculator

Tags: python, beginner, converting

After a few pages reading *Learning Python Hard Way*, I've decided to try to make a simple cm-to-inch calculator. I am very excited about this achievement, and I want someone to check my code. It works well, but i just need someone to  confirm everything is written well.

```
# cm to inch calculator
inch = 2.54 #centimeters
centimeters = int(input("Enter a number of centimeters"))
print "Entered number of %s centimeters is equal to %s inches" % (centimeters , centimeters / inch)
```

Answer (score 20):

Great work so far! And good on you for seeking review. In general, your code is pretty good, and works correctly. As you've asked, though, here are some suggestions for improvement.

---

The assignment:

```
inch = 2.54 #centimeters
```

is potentially confusing; instead, you could make it clear that it is a ratio:

```
CM_PER_INCH = 2.54
```

Note the `UPPERCASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES` name for a constant, per [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

---

```
centimeters = int(input("Enter a number of centimeters"))
```

There is no reason to limit the user to `int` input - why not allow `float`? Then they can enter and convert e.g. 4.2cm.

Also, this will fail with input that can't be converted to an integer (what if the user types `seven`?) - have a look at [this SO community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761) if you want to add validation.

---

```
print "Entered number of %s centimeters is equal to %s inches" % (centimeters , centimeters / inch)
```

This line is too long (see [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) again). Also, `%` formatting is a little old-fashioned, compared to [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). I would split this into two lines:

```
template = '{.2f}cm is equal to {.2f}"'
print template.format(centimeters, centimeters / CM_PER_INCH)
```

Or use line continuation:

```
print '{.2f}cm is equal to {.2f}"'.format(
    centimeters,
    centimeters / CM_PER_INCH
)
```

In use:

```
>>> print template.format(float(centimeters), centimeters / CM_PER_INCH)
5.00cm is equal to 1.97"
```

---

If you want another challenge, have a go at implementing the reverse calculation, and allowing the user to choose which way to convert.

Comment: A lot new things to learn, thank you so much! Although i have no idea what "template" is or "{.2f}", i guess i haven't reached that lectures yet. :D

Comment: What do you mean *"what "template" is"*? It's just a string, like your `"Entered number of %s centimeters is equal to %s inches"`. In terms of the `{.2f}`, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: Oh yes, it's just a string, my bad, thanks! :)

Answer (score 9):

Your code looks ok and probably does the job properly :-)

**Style**

However, it is not quite perfect. Python has a code style called [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and is definitly worth a read. Among other things, it says :

> Constants Constants are usually defined on a module level and written
>   in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples
>   include MAX_OVERFLOW and TOTAL .

Here, `inch` definitly looks like a constant so `INCH` would be better.

Also, not really important but you have an "extraneous whitespace" in `(centimeters , centimeters`.

**Functions**

Also, instead of having your conversion logic hidden in your logic handling input/output (with `print`), you might want to extract in in a simple function.

**Organisation**

Another to know if you are beginning with Python is that a good thing to do is to have your definitions of constants/functions/classes/etc in a file in such a way that you can re-use it later on (via imports mechanisms). If you don't want your logic "actually doing something" to mess with everything when you import your code, the technic is to use an [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

**Naming**

Naming is quite important in programming. Here `centimeters` in top of being long does not convey much meaning. I reckon `nb_cm` gives more information. Similarly, `NB_CM_IN_INCH` is better than `INCH`.

**User interface**

It could be a good idea to handle `float` values on top of integers.

**Python 3 (and notes about `input`)**

Final thing before I forget, from the way you have used `print`, I guess you are using Python 2. If you have no special reason to do so, you might want to start using Python 3 instead. You'll find a few things slightly different but you'll be better off learning directly on the latest versions so you have the good habits and nothing to un-learn.

However, I have to point out that `input` is "slightly" different on the 2 versions of Python. [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#input) from Python 3 corresponds to [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input)
while [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input) from Python 2 can be simulated in Python 3 with `eval(input())`.

Indeed, as you might or might not know, what you were doing is doing more that merely asking a string from the user, it was asking for Python code and handling it as such.

For instance,

> Enter a number of centimeters **2*3**
>
> Entered number of **6** centimeters is equal to 2.36220472441 inches

See how the number was evaluated. It looks good in theory or in you really know what you are doing. In most cases, using [`eval` directly or indirectly is considered a bad practice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)

**Final code**

Here's my version of the code (works in Python 2 but behavior is slightly different - cf note above).

```
NB_CM_IN_INCH = 2.54

def convert_cm_in_inch(val):
    """You can put docstrings here :)."""
    return val / NB_CM_IN_INCH

def convert_inch_in_cm(val):
    """And here :D."""
    return val * NB_CM_IN_INCH

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nb_cm = float(input("Enter a number of centimeters: "))
    print("Entered number of %s centimeters is equal to %s inches" % (nb_cm, convert_cm_in_inch(nb_cm)))
```

It seems like I have said many things so I want you not to take it as criticism of your good but as advices if you keep on programming in Python.

Comment: I guess i haven't learned "def" thing yet, i just passed strings and math operations so far and coz of that i have no idea what "def" is doing, but i hope i will learn that soon. :D Thanks a ton friend, you put so much effort to help!